# Is it a security risk setting EnableEventValidation="false" in this situation?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a page that contains a user control, when the user clicks an image button to take them to another page that displays details of the table row item they clicked an error occurs:

```
System.ArgumentException: Invalid postback or callback argument
```

I can stop this error from occurring if I set EnableEventValidation="false". Is this a security risk? If so, why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**This feature reduces the risk of unauthorized or malicious postback requests and callbacks. It is strongly recommended that you do not disable event validation.**

When the EnableEventValidation property is set to true, ASP.NET validates that a control event originated from the user interface that was rendered by that control [...]

see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.enableeventvalidation.aspx

I'd say if you keep the target page performing a single purpose - namely displaying detailed data - and make sure that the target page does not implement any potential security holes you can disable the EventValidation for THIS page. not in the web.config for the whole site!

**But I think it's better to investigate why you are getting this error!** Maybe it's a simple solution for you to redirect using Queryparameters, not form parameters to specify the data you want to display...