# Random error in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Please give me help regarding the random error comes within my web application using c# asp.net. The error is as follows:

```
"Validation of viewstate MAC failed. If this application is hosted by a Web Farm or cluster, ensure that <machineKey> configuration specifies the same validationKey and validation algorithm. AutoGenerate cannot be used in a cluster."
```

Comment: What version of .Net do you use? Try [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pl-PL/vstswebtest/thread/cd9c5c03-4bf3-472b-814a-cd498b190c57)

Comment: the error is giving you exactly what you need to place on web.config. Fix the same machine key for both web.configs

Comment: Error message is clear - are you running in a web farm? If so, you need to ensure that the `<machineKey>` of all instances is identical.

Comment: have a look this article : http://forums.asp.net/t/1622462.aspx/1

Comment: how to add machine key & what wil be value of machine key

Comment: This is for ASP.NET 2.0 but you'll probably find it useful:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649308.aspx

Comment: How is this a _random_ error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add enableEventValidation="false" property to page.
Refer link: http://weblogs.asp.net/albertpascual/archive/2008/08/11/fixing-the-validation-of-viewstate-mac-failed-error-issue.aspx

Comment: This shouldn't be recommended so easily http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9531363/is-it-a-security-risk-setting-enableeventvalidation-false-in-this-situation